# Source version control for Tomcat JSP load balancer environment

Tags: jsp, tomcat, svn, version-control, load-balancing

It's in the preliminary stages, but I'm setting up an environment which will leverage `load balancing`. Imagine a load balancing server with two web servers under it. Both web servers will be running `Tomcat` and `IIS`. As a result of this setup, the web files on both web servers will need to be in-sync. I need some kind of `version control software`, I think, maybe `SVN`

I've never setup `SVN` before and my understanding of it is it works very well for projects. But what about just random `JSP` files in a web directory? A user updates one JSP file on web server A; I want it such that that same JSP file is also updated on web server B.

If this is possible, how can I setup `version control software` for `Tomcat/JSP` files? I would appreciate any advice or help in guiding me in the right direction.

Thank you kindly.

I want to clarify something that's probably critical. When I say a random JSP file, I don't mean *anywhere* on either server. I'm talking about a web application. And in this web application, files will be to be added, updated, and maintained, similar to any development project. Which is why I was thinking some kind of version control software would solve this problem. Maybe I'm totally off-base, but I had thought version control software can work across multiple servers. no?

Comment: Sounds more like you're looking for `rsync` than version-control. version-control is one way to do this, but version-control solves a different problem than the one you have, which is *deployment*.

Comment: Interesting. Perhaps you expand on why I wouldn't use version control here, as well as how version control could accomplish my objective. I had thought because it's the same environment, i.e. development, deployment would only be an issue pushing to other environments, i.e. QA, staging, production. The servers are Windows, by the way. Thank you.

Comment: The exact environment (e.g. Windows) is not terribly relevant. Yes, you can use revision-control as a repository for configuration, etc. (and it's not a *bad idea* to do that), but you didn't say anything about wanting to keep the configuration *safe* -- only consistent. Revision-control is best used for situations where you want to be able to track changes over time, mark benchmarks for releases (sometimes called "tags"), etc. If you just want to synchronize configuration, you don't need the complexity of revision-control.